# Zend routing - url() doesn't fill variables

Tags: zend-framework, url, routes, helper

In my application, I need to apply this kind of address:

```
/film,pokaz,test-name,12.html
```

where: 'test-name' is some text and '12' is some ID.

Here's my router.ini:

```
showmovie.route = film,pokaz,:name,:id.html
showmovie.defaults.controller = movies
showmovie.defaults.action = show
showmovie.defaults.module = default
showmovie.defaults.name = ''
showmovie.defaults.id = ''
```

However, the url() helper seems to not fill those variables (:name and :id), so when I use it like:

```
$this->url(array('controller' => 'movies', 'action' => 'show', 'id' => 12, 'name' => 'testmovie'), 'showmovie', true, false);
```

it gives me this address:

```
/film,pokaz,:name,:id.html
```

Is there something wrong with my code or routing rule above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only separator you can use for named segments in the standard route type is `/`, so you'll need to do this as a regex route instead.